# Search by specific field Meteor React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-native

I try to filter a search component using only two fields. Right now, it returns results from all the fields within the list. Meaning if my search is 2, it will return every single objects that contains somehow 2.

The json file looks like this:

```
{
  "deputes" : [ {
    "depute" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "id_an" : "718902",
      "lieu_naissance" : "Brest (Finistère)",
      "nom_circo" : "Alpes-Maritimes",
      "nom_de_famille" : "Roussel",
      "num_circo" : 3
```

And a component to search that looks like this :

```
class Flat_List extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props)
    this._handleResults = this._handleResults.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data : null
    }
  }

  _handleResults(results){
    console.log('handle results')
    this.setState({data: results})
  }

   render() {
    let listitems = this.state.data
    if (this.state.data == null)  {
      listitems = this.props.deputies
    }
    return(
    <View>

      <SearchBar
        ref={(ref) => this.searchBar = ref}
        data={this.props.deputies}
        handleResults={this._handleResults}
        allDataOnEmptySearch = {true}
        showOnLoad = {true}
        hideBack
        autoCorrect= {false}
      />

      <List>
        <FlatList style={styles.flatListStyle}
          data={listitems}
          keyExtractor={(item)=> item._id}
          renderItem={({item})=>(
             <DeputyDetail deputy={item.depute} navigation={this.props.navigation} /> )} />
      </List>

    </View>
```

How can this component only search through two fields ? {num_circo} and {nom} ?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `'id', 'id_an', 'lieu_naissance'` field from every `depute` object so that `<SearchBar />` will not search for these.

You can add the following code to remove these fields:

```
componentWillMount(){
    var removeObjProps = ['id', 'id_an', 'lieu_naissance'];
    var filteredDep = Object.assign({}, this.props.deputies);
    filteredDep.deputies.forEach(function(dep){
        removeObjProps.forEach(function (val) {
            delete dep.depute[val];
        });
    });
    this.setState({filteredDep})
}
```

and replace your search bar with:

```
   <SearchBar
        ref={(ref) => this.searchBar = ref}
        data={this.state.filteredDep}
        handleResults={this._handleResults}
        allDataOnEmptySearch = {true}
        showOnLoad = {true}
        hideBack
        autoCorrect= {false}
      />
```

Comment: Not really an option to delete the others fields! I need the rest of the file to display the result

Comment: It will copy your deputies to a new object i.e filteredDep and will delete the fields in filteredDep. Your this.props.deputies will stay the same.